# How to invoke an EJB method without an h:form tag in a JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, hyperlink, invoke, ejb-3.1, commandlink

I want to invoke an EJB method when I click a link in my JSF website. At the moment I use an `h:commandLink` within an `h:form` tag to trigger the EJB method:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink value="Logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}"/>
</h:form>
```

Is there a way to do the same without the need of an `h:form` tag?

Comment: Guess, your current solution is a good one. You could try calling a URL and via `f:viewParam` call the EJB from the xhtml-template - this is a theoretical possibility. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798 for details.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want a form (but i don't get why) you can:

1. navigate to a servlet and execute your code there.
2. navigate to another jsf page and put your code inside a bean @PostContruct
3. navigate to another jsf page and put your code inside a bean method and use `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.listener}"/>`

Answer (score -1):

It has to be inside a form AFAIK.